# Discord/node.js regex match, replace string, extract replaced string

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

The intention is, someone posts a twitter link, the bot takes the message content, replaces twitter.com/x.com with "fxtwitter.com", extracts the corrected URL and posts it in the channel, replying to the user.

I've managed to get this working fine by having the bot send `content: twitterReplace` but obviously that quotes the whole message, I only want the URL.

So far I have this. I hope you can see what I'm trying to do here. **I'm not even sure if `let twitterReplaced = twitterReplace` is actually needed.**

Bear with me.....

```
client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
  const twitterTest = new RegExp(/\b(https\b:\/\/(x.com\/|twitter.com\/))(.*\/status)/gm);
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (
    twitterTest.test(message.content)
  ) {
    let twitterReplace = message.content.replace(
      /\b(https\b:\/\/(x.com|twitter.com))/gm,
      "https://fxtwitter.com"
    );
    let twitterReplaced = twitterReplace
    let twitterCut = new RegExp(/g\b(https\b:\/\/(fxtwitter.com)).+?(?=\?)/gm)
    let twitterFixed = twitterCut.match(twitterReplaced) 
    message.reply({content: twitterFixed, allowedMentions: {repliedUser: false}});
  }
});
```

However the above gives an error that an empty message can't be sent.

Comment: For twitterCut, did you intend to include the character g at the beginning of `/g\b(https\b:\/\/(fxtwitter.com)).+?(?=\?)/gm`? Also you are right in saying that `let twitterReplaced = twitterReplace` is not needed

Comment: It's also worth noting that `twitterFixed` is an array (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), so `content` might fail due to expecting a string. To find just the first match, `exec` might be better suited.

Comment: Off-topic: Down-voting costs reputation, so unless the person somehow didn't know that they likely felt there was a good reason. On-topic: The `\b` of `https:\b` seems unnecessary, and twitterCut should not use the `m | multiline` flag as a single match will not be across multiple lines.

Comment: @LukeTrenaman once I stringified it (is that the term lol), it worked perfectly. Thank you so much. I'm not sure I can select a comment as the answer? Oh and also, no I did not mean to add the `/g`, that was a typo in the code.

Comment: Also thank you to @l3l_aze I've amended the regex. Very grateful to you both